# CakePHP setflash page refresh doesn't keep language in url

Tags: cakephp, localization, routes

I have a multi language website, but when I don't do a redirect with a `setFlash`, it deletes the language from the url. Example: if the contactform doesn't validate, it just does a `setFlash` without the `redirect`, so that user input data is not lost. But it does refresh the page and deletes the language part from my url. This does not happen when I do a `redirect` after my `setFlash`, because I give the `language` param with the `redirect`. Work flow:

I start on the page **website.com/eng/contact** (notice the language part). I fill in the contact form and fill in all required inputs. It redirects me to **website.com/eng/contact/send**. That's great and what I want. But when I don't give an valid email adres for example, it display an error (great), but the url has changed to **website.com/forms/contact** (notice the missing language part, and it doesn't use my routes). What am I doing wrong? My code:

**Formscontroller.php**

```
public function contact() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Form->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Form->validates()) {        
            if($this->Form->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'contact_success', 'language' => $this->Session->read('Config.language')));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Er ging iets mis met het versturen van uw contactformulier, probeer het opnieuw.'), 'flash_error');
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Niet alle verplichte velden zijn ingevuld.'), 'flash_error');
        }
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/:language/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

Router::connect('/:language/contact', array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'contact'), array('language' => 'ned|eng'));
Router::connect('/:language/contact/verzonden', array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'contact_success'), array('language' => 'ned'));
Router::connect('/:language/contact/send', array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'contact_success'), array('language' => 'eng'));

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'), array('language' => 'eng|ned'));
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));

CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: I kinda doubt that `setFlash()` issues a redirect, pretty sure the request is just going straight to the URL that is set for the form, and you're seeing what you are seeing because there is _no_ redirect. That being said, please show your form code and the generated HTML output. On a side note you're better off using persistent parameters instead of passing the language around manually. ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I didn't even think about that! That is indeed the reason why it isn't working. But how can I set the action of my form with the language? I tried `echo $this->Form->create('Form', array('role' => 'form', 'url' => array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'contact', 'language' => $this->Session->read('Config.langugage'))));`, but that is not working. What do you mean by using persistent parameters?

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, it works fine for me. Regarding persistent parameters, see the `persist` option: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#router-api**, also: **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+persist**.

Comment: It does not add the language to the link is what I meant. But I will try it again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong direction for my problem. As [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) points out in his comment on my question, it had to do with the action of my form, it didn't have the language part in it. So thanks to [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for pointing me in the right direction!